# Why is incognito mode not working while using puppeteer-extra plugin with puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am using puppeteer-extra package with stealth plugin of puppeteer. While using the default puppeteer package, incognito shows up , but while using puppeteer-extra plugin, even while initializing the incognito context, the incognito window doesn't open up. Any idea if its some compatibility issue or someone already came across this problem.

I have tried with args passing "--incognito" mode and also using the context method.

While using --incognito parameter it opens parent window with incognito but while using newPage(), it open a second window which is without incognito flow.

Two approaches I had used

Importing puppeteer extra package:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import pluginStealth from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';

Method 1:
 const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
 const page = await context.newPage();

Method 2 :
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args:[--incognito]});
```

I expect that while using puppeteer-extra package, the behavior should be same as using puppeteer.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

This appears to be caused by a bug in the `puppeteer-extra` library. When you open a puppeteer instance with puppeteer-extra, the browser instance is hotpatched to better integrate newly opened pages with plugins.

Unfortunately the current implementation of `browser._createPageInContext` (as of version 2.1.3) doesn't correctly handle which browser context the new page should belong to once it's opened.

### The fix

The fix is [this pull request](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/pull/47).
Specifically, you need to change this line

```
return async (contextId) => {
```

to this

```
return async function (contextId) {
```

so that `arguments` on the next line is evaluated correctly

```
const page = await originalMethod.apply(context, arguments)
```